# Why was it necessary to restart apache webserver to copy files via php on newly mounted filer?

Tags: permissions, mount, apache-httpd, solaris, php

**Scenario**

- allready running Apache Webserver 2.4.2 on Solaris 5.10
- newly added nfs mount as target for copying files via php
- executing cp via shell with the same user as the webserver works
- copying via Webserver/php doesn't work, it gives permission denied in the apache error log (no matter if using phps copy, exec or shell_exec)

**Solution**

After restarting the apache webserver everything works fine.

**Question**

Why is that? As far as I know file- and directory-permissions are (have to be!) checked per/on execution, or not? Plus if not calling something that uses the new mountpoint, the apache doesn't even know of it.

Comment: do you have caching enabled? usually mod_cache or similar

Comment: No, it isn't enabled: All modules containing cache in its name aren't  loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be (although I've never done this before, I've always had the nfs mount up first) is that the running user didn't have access until it was reloaded - either it didn't know about it or something along those lines. Never tried this before though so I'm not really sure